# Why is stdout not being redirected in this case?

Tags: c, linux, unix, stdout

I have some very simple code that prints to stdout/stderr and takes input on stdin. I notice that if I try to redirect stdout to a file, the file is blank. However, if I run the command via the terminal I am seeing the stdout output. Is there a reason that the output is not being redirected? Is there a way I can force the output to be captured?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello, World! stdout\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Hello, World! stderr\n");
    
    while(1)
    {
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t size;
        getline(&line, &size, stdin);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", line);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Executing `./1.out > out.txt` shows no stdout output on the terminal and has a blank out.txt file when I kill the process.

Executing `./1.out` shows stdout and stderr output and waits for stdin.

```
$ ./1.out 
Hello, World! stdout
Hello, World! stderr
```

If I get rid of the loop and have the program just print and exit then the output capture works fine.

Comment: Output to files is buffered. If you kill the script before the buffer is flushed, nothing is written.

Comment: `fflush(stdout);` to flush the write buffer

Comment: Normally you should check the return value of `getline` to see if end-of-file has occurred, and exit the program gracefully (by calling `exit()` or returning from `main`) after finishing any other work.  This will ensure that all buffers are flushed and all output is written, if you end the terminal input normally with `Ctrl-D` instead of killing the process.  As it stands, when EOF is reached, your program will spin and write an infinite number of newlines to the output.